# How To clear all the markers from google map using v3 api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

I want to clear all the markers when i click on a submit button. If i have a latitude and longitude and want to clear that marker, how can i do that. Also if i search any route i want to clear all the marker already loaded.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to help.  How were the markers added?  A link to your map (or a jsfiddle) that shows the issue would be useful.  Typically I keep a reference to the markers that have been added to the map in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For removing markers from the map after insertion, you should keep track of them with a global variable:

```
var markers = [];
```

Then, whenever you add a marker to the map, add the marker to the `markers` array as well:

```
markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(20, 20)
});
```

---

To clear all the markers from the map, you could use the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
    markers[i].setMap(null);
```

If you'd like to simultaneously clear the `markers` array, you could use this:

```
for (var i = markers.length-1; i >= 0; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
    markers.pop();
}
```

or this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
    markers[i].setMap(null);
markers = [];
```

---

If you'd like to remove a marker based on latitude and longitude values as a `LatLng` object, you can use the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    if (markers[i].getPosition().equals(latLng)
        markers[i].setMap(null);
}
```

If you simply have the coordinates, you can use the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    if (markers[i].getPosition().equals(latLng)
        markers[i].setMap(null);
}
```

Comment: For what it’s worth, in your ‘simultaneously clear all markers’ option you meant `i--` (thanks for the hint though!).